# How do I go from an infinite amount of instantaneous rates to an average rate?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, average, related-rates

I have a function that gives me rate at a point (the derivative) and I have a value for average rate that was experimentally calculated. How would I go about creating an expression to solve for a theoretical average rate. My intuition tells me to integrate the rate function and divide by the total number of things I added, but that makes me divide by infinity and average rate = 0, which is not correct.
If it helps, I am dealing with volume flow rate, where dV/dt is volume flow rate and I need to find average over some time t for a physics experiment.
Thanks

Comment: You integrate $\frac {dV}{dt}$ over the time period of interest and divide by the time interval to get the average flow rate.

Comment: @RossMillikan thank you! Is there an intuitive way to understand why this works?

Comment: @DaBestGamer The starting point for your intuition should be an intuitive understanding of the (definite) integral. Intuitively, the integral of a function over an interval is the product of the length of the interval and the average value of the function over that interval. Thus the definite integral can be approximated by averaging the values at $n$ evenly spaced points and multiplying by the length of the interval:$$(b-a)\cdot\frac{f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)}n.$$ This is called a *Riemann sum*. (The more general Riemann sum with unevenly spaced points uses an appropriately weighted average.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average rate of change is $\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}$. The instantaneous rate of change is $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is the instantaneous rate of change.

The total change is the integral of the derivative: $\Delta V = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{dV}{dt}dt$. That also tells us that $\Delta t=t_2-t_1$

So $\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t }=\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{dV}{dt} dt$

More generally $\overline F = \frac{1}{x_2-x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(x) dx$. This integral expression defines an average of the function. It is the Mean Value Theorem for integrals.